# ARM templates and validation of mandatory tag values against AAD

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-policy

I want to create policies using an ARM template for newly created resources that have automatically pre-populated or validated tags such as CreatedBy or BusinessOwner, and their values ​​will include the names of the users who created them or who are responsible for the budget allocated to the Azure resource.

I would like the policy to specify that if a resource is created and a tag value is set, that value is validated against AAD users. It would be best if the ARM buildin function existed and the template looked something like this:

```
    CreatedBy
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags['CreatedBy']",
              "exists": "false"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "append",
          "details": [
            {
              "field": "tags['CreatedBy']",
              "value": "[GetAADUsername()]"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

According to the list of functions that are currently supported for ARM templates, this is not possible, see. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions.

But I want to ask if anyone has solved it and does not have a solution for defining policies for these basic tags and that their values ​​are not just ad hoc strings, but verified values ​​against real objects in AAD.

Thank you.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT The answer is useful with interesting links. But definitely it can't be considered as a solution. The solution should be simple and declarative as in my example or in https://jrudlin.github.io/2019-07-18-azure-policy-createdon-date/, but not the solution using EventHub. So I'll leave it open to possible other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

***Currently , Its not possible to add Created by or Updated by based on Azure AD UPN using Azure Policy.***

***As an alternative you can use Azure Event Hubs and Azure Functions to create the tags in order to manage the subscription resources based on who created it or modified it .***

***You can follow this [`Azure Community Blog`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/tagging-azure-resources-with-a-creator/ba-p/1479819) by `Anthony Watherston` on how to tag resourced with a creator tag or you can refer this [`Github Repo`](https://github.com/tomhollander/AzureSetCreatedTags) created by `Tom Hollander` on how to add tags like createdBy, ModifiedBy, createdDate and ModifiedDate.***

Comment: Thank you. Those links are great.